# mexPrintf does not display anything

Tags: octave, mex

I am trying to use MEX-files in Octave. For starters, I'm simply trying to call the MEX-file so it can print "this is a test". My `mexfile.cpp` is:

```cpp
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction (int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
  mexPrintf ("Hello, World!\n");
  return;
}
```

and I'm trying to call the file by entering the following into the command window:

```matlab
mkoctfile --mex mexfile.cpp;
```

It appears the file is compiling but nothing is being printed. Any idea as to why that is the case?

Comment: mkoctfile only compiles it, you still have to call the function

Comment: Okay, so it sort of worked. It's printing "Hello, world" now. However, I receive a warning before it does. Then after the print of "Hello, world", I receive an error. I'm calling it like this:

mkoctfile --mex mexfile.cpp;
mexfile.cpp;

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't like guessing, what warning, what error message?

Comment: Call the function with `mexfile`. It is like calling any other Octave function now.